# Unable to start Hbase Thrift server

Tags: php, ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, thrift

I have install Hadoop 1.2.1 and Hbase 0.94.8 in psudo-distributed mode in my ubuntu system running Ubuntu 12.04. Everything is working fine and all the deamons are running. In order to access hbase using php I downloaded and installed thrift 0.9.1.

> $ thrift -version
>
> Thrift version 0.9.1

But when I try to start the thrift server using the command

```
$ /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/bin/hbase thrift start
```

the thrift server begins to start. But at a certain point the terminal hangs. the last few lines of the terminal were

> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 9095
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 9095 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 9095
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 9095
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9095
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 DEBUG thrift.ThriftServerRunner: Using binary protocol
>
> 14/02/19 15:30:48 INFO thrift.ThriftServerRunner: starting TBoundedThreadPoolServer on /0.0.0.0:9090; min worker threads=16, max worker threads=1000, max queued requests=1000

after waiting for about 15 minutes I tried to open

```
http://localhost:9090
```

in my web browser while the terminal was still hanged. The page did not open but the terminal resumed showing the error message

> #
>
> # java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> # -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
>
> #   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 18526"...
>
> Killed

Please suggest me what to do.

Regards

Comment: The dependency table at http://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.94.8-gphd-2.1.0.0 says Thrift 0.8.0. have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following command for starting hbase thrift service:

```
bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
```

Comment: How to start hbase thrift service in windows?